# Can I license my Minecraft mod with WTFPL with heavily modified code from GPL licensed mod (having author's permission)?

Tags: licensing, gpl

I want to license my [Minecraft mod](https://github.com/mchorse/blockbuster) with WTFPL. However, I have a small section of code which I incorporated from [other mod](https://github.com/EchebKeso/Mocap), licensed under GPL, in the first release of my mod.

In the recent version (see `dev` branch of my mod) I refactored and rewrote it from scratch. I also got permission (see README of my mod) from the author of the other mod to use his code.

In this situation, do I have a freedom over choosing which license I can choose, in this case WTFPL, or must I stick only to GPL compatible licenses?

I'm still going to give credit to the original author of the mod, but I'm unsure about my licensing situation and control over my code.

Thank you for attention!

Comment: It depends what kind of permission you got. A permission to use that other code, or a permission to redistribute it (or a work derived from it) under a different license. Anyway, we cannot tell you, you have to talk to that other guy.

Comment: Here's the screenshot of [the permission request](http://i.imgur.com/lc1lJB5.png). I didn't asked him about the license switch, but I'm asking you, people, since I mentioned that I rewrote his code using completely different technique. By the way, I'm total noob in the licensing.

Comment: You still have to ask him, telling about the license change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle if you copy one line from a GPL or LGPL and distribute it you will be guilty of copyright infringement unless your software is distributed under (L)GPL. This is why they are called viral licenses.

You have to get the original author to license the code to you under a more permissive license. If you know you want to use WTFPLC the easiest is to just ask him to license the code to you under that license, but BSD, MIT, or MPL could also work.

In general all contributors to a piece of GPL software have to agree to license it under a different license, so this excercise is more complicated when there are many contributors to the GPL software.

Comment: Just a note for OP: I wouldn't get my hopes up that someone who used the GPL would, nor even *could*, give permission to use a license as permissive as WTFPL. It's likely that the person licensing the code based their code on someone else's who licensed it as GPL....

Comment: "If you copy one line" - nothing can force to have the same license. You have the choice of using the license, or being accused of copyright infringement. You are free to figure out the chances of going to court, losing in court, and paying the price. If you copy one line that price would very low. For example if Microsoft discovered that some idiot copied one GPL licensed line of code into the Word source code, and the product has shipped, it would _not_ become GPL licensed.

Comment: Your opening statement is false. Not even in principle. It depends on a lot of factors, particularly how special / creative the line(s) are. Copying `printf("Application Starting")` is not considered creative work.

Comment: @gnasher729 you are right. I've specified it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I asked the author for permission to relicense. He gave me permission, so my problem is solved. However, this is really saddening that (L)GPL is advertised as free license, forces users to license their software under (L)GPL. Anyway, what about contributions? So if I license my software under GPL, and somebody contributes and creates a class, he basically has copyright on this class? Therefore disabling me from switching to another license? What about MIT license or WTFPL, is it works this way too with contributions?